# How to suspend my laptop when I close the lid?

Tags: power-management

Since I installed 11.10 the system does not suspend when I close the lid.

In Power Management, the values for both battery and plug are set to suspend. When I just click on suspend, it works fine.

Comment: There are multiple bugs with the suspend feature and various hardware configurations. You might have run into the UI/configuration defect however https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/860485

Answer (score 1):

A lot of the settings (including whether to suspend when the lid is closed, iirc) that were hidden by both Unity and GNOME 3 are still available in gconf.  Install the `gnome-tweak-tool` package to change them.